# Ember Accessing Model Array with forEach()

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js, ember-data

I'm having an issue with upgrading ember-data form `0.X` to `1.0.0-beta12`. My ember.js version is `1.7.1`. In my controller I have a method `contentChanged():` which loops through my model:

```
this.get('model').forEach(function(story) {
    mutableComments.pushObject(story);
});
```

Since upgrading ember-data the structure for `this.get('model');` has changed so `forEach()` isn't finding my array.

Before Update:
[image: Before]

After Update:

[image: After]

The content originally is an `array[20]` but now it is a class which has a content property `array[20]`. I need to iterate through these items but the current code does not work.

I have tried. `this.get('model').toArray()`but this returned an empty array. How do I access the content array?

Edit: To add more context, the application uses this code to iterate through story objects and place them in a `currentStories` array. We do this with a `Ember.Mixin` that has feedSettings and use the Mixin where we want to create the feed.

```
    App.FeedRouteMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
        /* When using the FeedRouteMixin, create a feedSettings object in the
         * route with any of the following properties. If a property is missing,
         * it will take the default value expressed below.

        feedSettings: {
            mountPoint: [],
            canCompose: true,
            firstLoad: true,
            ableToLoadMore: true,
            hasNewStories: false,
            complexFeed: true,
            feedType: "course"      // "course", "home", "profile" "announcement"
            canAnnounce: false,
            isAnnouncement: false,
            content: [],
            into: "user"
        },*/
        /**
         * Renders the feed using the feedSettings
         */
        renderFeed: function() {
            var fs = this.get("feedSettings");
            var feedController = this.controllerFor('feed');
            feedController.set('mountPoint', fs.mountPoint);
            feedController.set('canCompose', (typeof fs.canCompose != "undefined") ? fs.canCompose : true);
            feedController.set('firstLoad', (typeof fs.firstLoad != "undefined") ? fs.firstLoad : true);
            feedController.set('ableToLoadMore', (typeof fs.ableToLoadMore != "undefined") ? fs.ableToLoadMore : true);
            feedController.set('hasNewStories', (typeof fs.hasNewStories != "undefined") ? fs.hasNewStories : false);
            feedController.set('complexFeed', (typeof fs.complexFeed != "undefined") ? fs.complexFeed : true);
            feedController.set('feedType', (typeof fs.feedType != "undefined") ? fs.feedType : "course");
            feedController.set('is_announcement', (typeof fs.isAnnouncement != "undefined") ? fs.isAnnouncement : false);
            feedController.set('content', fs.content);

            this.render("feed", {
                outlet: "feed",
                into: fs.into,
                controller: feedController
            });
        },
        renderTemplate: function(controller, model){
            this.render();
            this.renderFeed();
        }
    });
```

This is where we use the mixin:

```
App.HomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend(App.FeedRouteMixin, App.FlagMixin, {
    feedSettings: {
        into: "home",
        feedType: "home"
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this.feedSettings.content =  this.store.findAll('feedstory');
        controller.set('model', model);
        // console.log(model);
    },
    activate: function() {
        App.set("title", "Welcome!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Coming to this completely cold, but: `this.get('model').content.forEach`?

Comment: Side note: I think you can replace the entire loop with `mutableComments.pushObjects(this.get('model'))` (old) or `mutableComments.pushObjects(this.get('model').content)` (new, if I'm right above). Note the `s` on [`pushObjects`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html#method_pushObjects).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've tried this.get('model').content and it just returns null, unfortunately. Thanks for the `pushObjects()` advice.

Comment: may be show us the code where are you setting model property, may be corresponding route..

Comment: @kumkanillam added more code see edit :)

Comment: Where is the model hook ?..where are you initializing `model` property ?

Comment: It set's the FeedControllers model/content in `renderFeed:` 

`var feedController = this.controllerFor('feed');`
`feedController.set('content', fs.content);`

Comment: am not sure try this instead `feedController.set('model', fs.content);`

Comment: also in setupController hook try calling `this._super(controller,model)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125528/discussion-between-chris-parry-and-kumkanillam).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really looks like now you have a `PromiseArray` which is both, `Promise` and `Array`. Have you tried to resolve the Promise:

```
this.get('model').then(function(model) {
  model.forEach(function(story) {
    mutableComments.pushObject(story);
  });
});
```

However know that the `then` will execute async.

Comment: This solved the problem so I've accepted the answer, Thanks again.